# Cannot delete a record by retrieving only one column of a record. Any insights?

Tags: python, tkinter

**What I have done:**

I have created a table Item, (in python with mysql connection to store the said table in the mysql database) which contains 3 columns (ICODE, INAME, ITYPE). Then, I have created a tkinter gui window with 3 textboxes that allows users to enter ICODE,INAME,ITYPE inputs. It has two buttons, Add Item and Delete Item.

**What I am trying to do:**

I wrote the following code that would accept an ICODE and delete the record having the entered ICODE

**Code:**

```
def delitem():
    icode=tcode.get("1.0","end-1c")
    #Database Connection
    if icode=="":
        tk.messagebox.showinfo("Please enter a code")
    else:
        import mysql.connector as sqltor
                                   
        connection=sqltor.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd=" 
                                                     ",database="apparelstore")
        tkcursor=connection.cursor(prepared=True)
        sql="delete from item where icode=%s"
        val="icode"
        tkcursor.execute(sql,val)
        connection.commit()
        tk.messagebox.showinfo("Item deleted")
        tkcursor.close()
```

**Error:**

> Incorrect number of arguments executing prepared statement

Comment: It should be `tkcursor.execute(sql, (val,))` as second argument is expected to be a tuple or list.

Comment: Did you mean `val` to be a string, or are you assigning a variable to it? Also if you dont pass in tuple as second argument, it will take additional `len('icode')`(ie 5) more arguments and hence the error you got.

Comment: I think it should be `tkcursor.execute(sql, (icode,))` instead as `icode` contain the value you enter.

Comment: @acw1668 I tried it and it worked now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The statement `tkcursor.execute(sql, val)` should be:

```
tkcursor.execute(sql,(val,))
```

Comment: I tried this and it still does not work, no errors either

Comment: Instead of `tkcursor.close()`, you should close the connection, i.e., it should be `connection.close()`. I don't know if this will help, but just try and see.

Comment: As @acw1668 has stated, the problem was with `tkcursor.execute(sql,val)`, which should have been `tkcursor.execute(sql,(icode,))`.  But what you pointed out is also an error, I should have closed the connection, not the cursor